# Error in Python when implementing binary search tree

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to implement a binary search tree using Python:

Here is my tree_node class:

```
class tree_node:
    def  __init__(self,val,rightChild,leftChild):
        self.val = val
        self.rightChild = rightChild
        self.leftChild = leftChild
```

and here is my binary tree class:

```
class binary_tree:
    def __init__(self,baseNode):
        self.baseNode = baseNode
    
    def addTreeNode(self,treeNode):
       current = self.baseNode
       while current:
             prev = current
             if treeNode.val < current.val:
                 current = current.rightChild
                 if prev.val < treeNode.val < current.val:
                     prev.rightChild = treeNode
                     treeNode.rightChild = current
                     break
             if treeNode.val > current.val:
                 current = current.leftChild
                 if prev.val<treeNode.val<current.val:
                     prev.leftChild = treeNode
                     treeNode.rightChild = current
       if treeNode.val<current.val:
             current.rightChild = treeNode
       elif treeNode.val>current.val:
             current.leftChild = treeNode
    
    def print_tree(self):
        currentL = self.baseNode
        currentR = self.baseNode
        while currentR:
           print("",currentR.val)
           currentR = currentR.rightChild
        while currentL:
            currentL = currentL.leftChild      
            print("",currentL.val)
```

My main:

```
zero = tree_node(0,None,None)
minusone = tree_node(-1,None,None)
one = tree_node(1,None,None)
minustwo = tree_node(-2,None,None)
two= tree_node(2,None,None)
bst = binary_tree(zero)
bst.addTreeNode(minustwo)
bst.addTreeNode(one)
bst.addTreeNode(two)
bst.addTreeNode(minusone)
bst.print_tree()
```

However when I try to call the `addTreeNode()` method it shows me a

> Error: `while current.rightChild and current.leftChild` Attribute Error: 'NoneType doesn't have attribute rightChild'`.

If I flip the `bst.addTreeNode(minustwo)` with the `bst.addTreeNode(minusone)` line it prints `0 0 -1 -2 1 2` as it should so I suspect the issue is somewhere in these lines:

```
             if prev.val < treeNode.val < current.val:
                 prev.rightChild = treeNode
                 treeNode.rightChild = current
                 break
```

but I don't understand why it shouldn't it be this.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that after assigning a new reference to `current`, your code does not first verify that this new reference is not `None`. It immediately performs a comparison with `current.val`. And so, if `current` happens to have become `None` by a previous assignment, this will bring about the error you got.

A similar problem will occur once the loop has finished -- you can see this from the `while` condition. Yet, right after the loop, your code accesses `current.val` again.

To fix this, completely remove those inner-most `if` blocks that start with `if prev.val < treeNode.val < current.val:` or similar. Besides that they access `current.val` without first ensuring `current` is not `None`, the rest of that `if` block **replaces** a subtree with the new node, which potentially destroys part of the tree. This makes no sense. Remove that code.

Also make sure that if `current` has received a new value, no other code executes, not even an `if` condition, before checking the `while` condition. So the second `if` should become an `elif`

And to fix the bug you have *after* the loop, you should use `prev` instead of `current`.

The corrected code:

```
    def addTreeNode(self,treeNode):
        current = self.baseNode
        prev = None
        while current:
            prev = current
            if treeNode.val < current.val:
                current = current.rightChild
            elif treeNode.val > current.val:
                current = current.leftChild
        if not prev:
            self.baseNode = treeNode    
        elif treeNode.val < prev.val:
            prev.rightChild = treeNode
        elif treeNode.val > prev.val:
            prev.leftChild = treeNode
```

I should probably also warn that your `print_tree` method is not correct. So I provide here an implementation that prints it sideways (90° rotated counter clockwise):

```
    def print_tree(self):
        def dfs(node, indent=""):
            if node:
                dfs(node.rightChild, "  " + indent)
                print(indent, node.val)
                dfs(node.leftChild, "  " + indent)
        dfs(self.baseNode)
```

Comment: But if we are in the right side of the tree and treeNode.val > current.val where do you set that treeNode.rightChild  = current?  so that the link is not lost between the root and the current tree node?

Comment: In this algorithm `treeNode` always is inserted as a **leaf**, so `treeNode.rightChild` is never going to be set. Both its `rightChild` and `leftChild` attributes remain `None` (until later maybe another new node is inserted below it).

Comment: I want to add a node at all cases not only when it is a leaf

Comment: You don't understand. It covers all cases. But the tree always grows downward. At the moment a new node is added, it is a leaf. It doesn't **remain** a leaf, as later other nodes get added below it. But in essence, the way insertion happens in a binary search tree is like that: new nodes are always added at a place where there is no node yet.

Comment: "In this algorithm treeNode always is inserted as a leaf".But what if there is a value already in the tree which is bigger than the value of the treeNode?

Comment: Then it is inserted at the left side of that value, following its `leftChild` reference. Please read the Wikipedia article on this subject, especially the section on [insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Insertion)